# Re try method on certain exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have the following method which uses a proxy to retrieve information from a server. Sometimes due to a bad proxy I get `SocketException`, `SSLException`, `SSLHandshakeException` or `ConnectException`

As you can see in my method I am already using `catch (IOException ioe)` I need to do that in order to get the contents of server response if the server returns anything other than code 200.

How can I make the method retry in case of the above exceptions?

```
public String getMeta() throws IOException
{

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try
    {
        String url = "https://api.myapp.com/meta";
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);

        if (useProxy && fullProxy)
        {
            myapp.Proxy proxyCustom = getRandomProxy();
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyCustom.getProxyIp(), proxyCustom.getProxyPort()));
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        }

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("host", urlObj.getHost());
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        int responseCode = 0;

        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        is = con.getInputStream();
        writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
        {
            HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) con;
            int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != 200)
            {
                is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Use a loop or recursion. If you wanna avoid that stuff and endless recursion/loops, without extra logic just put everything from the try-block into a new method. Which you can then call another time.

Comment: `How can I make the method retry` Do you want to retry once, or continually retry until no exception is thrown?

Comment: @copeg I hope there is an simple way of setting how times it should retry, but it it's too complicated I will do with just trying once.

Comment: You could have have the `getMeta` throw the IOException, and have the caller catch it - from within the catch of the caller call `getMeta` again

Comment: you can use a flag in your catch that indicates that you want to call that method again; after that add a finally block and check inside it if that flag is active in order to re-call the method. Aside, if you are catching the exception maybe is better not throw them in your method signature

Comment: You could wrap the try/catch block in a while loop with some number of retries. Break out of the loop if you succeed (make it to the end of the try block) or hard error. If you meet/exceed the number of retries, the while loop will break out for you. You could also optimize so you're not recreating objects every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do is create a new retry method and invoke it at the end of your getMeta() method so it is called in only in case of abnormalities
I am assuming you should call the retry only a few times and hence getMeta should throw some exception like RetryException after certain number of times

```
public String getMeta() throws IOException, RetryException
{

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try
    {
        String url = "https://api.myapp.com/meta";
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);

        if (useProxy && fullProxy)
        {
            myapp.Proxy proxyCustom = getRandomProxy();
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyCustom.getProxyIp(), proxyCustom.getProxyPort()));
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        }

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("host", urlObj.getHost());
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        int responseCode = 0;

        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        is = con.getInputStream();
        writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");

        return writer.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
        {
            HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) con;
            int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != 200)
            {
                is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");

                return writer.toString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retryGetMeta();
}


private String retryGetMeta()
{
   try
   {
       return getMeta();
   }
   finally
   {
       //Do your stuff
   }
}

public RetryException extends Exception
{
    private   String message =  "Retries exceeded";

      public String getMessage()
      {
         return message;
      }

}
```

If an exception is thrown in your getMeta(), catch will do its stuff as you are doing now, but after that , retryGetMeta will be called

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so this would not get recalled in case of IOException right? but it would get recalled when SocketException, SSLException, SSLHandshakeException or ConnectException is thrown?

Comment: Yes if you want to return writer.toString() incase of IOException then retry won't be called. Imodified code to return writer in case of IOException , all other exceptions it will call retry

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the method retry in case of the above exceptions?

One way shown below is to have the `getMeta` method actually throw the IOException. You can then then have a `caller` method recursively call itself due to any caught Exception.

> I hope there is an simple way of setting how times it should retry

To be able to call the method `n` number of times, pass in the number of times as an argument and deal with the stopping criteria logic accordingly. For example:

```
public String caller(int total) throws IOException{
    return callerImpl(1, total);
}

public String callerImpl(int current, int total) throws IOException{
    try{
        return getMeta();
    }catch(IOException e){
        current++;
        if ( current > total ){
            throw e;//or return null or empty string, depending upon upstream requirements
        }
        return callerImpl(current, total);
    }

    return null;
}
```

In getMeta:

```
try{
    ....
}catch(IOException io){
    //log or handle io
    throw io;
}
```

Note the above doesn't deal with the logging/logic of the thrown exceptions, which you may want to handle in some way.